# REGEXP_REPLACE to remove list of words from company name column

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

```
select 'Owens 1245 Coning COM CO LTD INC CORP INC', REGEXP_REPLACE(
      UPPER(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(regexp_replace('Owens 1245 Coning COM CO LTD', '(*[[:punct:]])', ' '),'(\s[0-9]+\s)|(^[0-9]+\s)|(\s[0-9]+$)',' ')),'( ){2,}', ' '))), 
      '\\b'||'CO|LTD|INC|CORP'||'\\W'
      ,'') CLEARTEXT
from dual;
```

if i run the above query it removes all the stop words except "CO" and gives the output : OWENS CONING COM CO

however i need the output to be like : OWENS CONING COM

Comment: May be you need to add another couple of examples with expected output to clarify the requirement. What are considered as stop words?

Comment: There are too many replaces on your select wich means that there are the same amount of rules or more. So add the rules of your replace statement  so we can help!

Comment: Apologies as my requirements were not clear

Comment: Apologies as my requirements were not clear. The rules are :-  1) Replace all the punctuation(special char) with "Space".  2) Remove all the numeric words (only numeric words).  3) Remove all the stopwords from the name, the list of stopwords (CO|LTD|INC|CORP) is user defined and coming from a table concatenated with (Pipe |).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this but be sure to test with every combination of "stop words" and "good" data that could exist in the column.  This regex looks for your "stop words" where followed by a space or the end of the line (the space is consumed) and replaces with nothing.  I added surrounding brackets to show there are no spaces after the final TRIM( )):

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
     select 'Owens 1245 Coning COM CO LTD. INC CORP. INC' from dual
   )
   select str original, '[' || trim(regexp_replace(upper(str), '(\d+|CO|LTD|INC|CORP)([[:punct:]])?( |$)', '')) || ']' CLEARTEXT
   from tbl;

ORIGINAL
-----------------------------------------
CLEARTEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Owens 1245 Coning COM CO LTD. INC CORP. INC
[OWENS CONING COM]


SQL>
```

EDIT: Modified the regex to to allow for optional punctuation after the stop words.

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as 
(
select '121 R.S. Hughes3 Company, Inc.' SUPPLIER_NAME from dual
)
select a.SUPPLIER_NAME , REGEXP_REPLACE(
      REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(regexp_replace(a.SUPPLIER_NAME , '(*[[:punct:]])', ' '),'(\s[0-9]+\s)|(^[0-9]+\s)|(\s[0-9]+$)',' ')),'( ){2,}', ' '))), ''),
  '(CO|LTD|INC|CORP)?( |$)'
  ,' ') CLEARTEXT
from t a
;
```

Thanks Gary
Tried to alter the original query where in i added only the stopwords query provided by you which gives me the desired output.

Thanks again.

Comment: Apologies as my requirements were not clear. The rules are :- 1) Replace all the punctuation(special char) with "Space". 2) Remove all the numeric words (only numeric words). 3) Remove all the stopwords from the name, the list of stopwords (CO|LTD|INC|CORP) is user defined and coming from a table concatenated with (Pipe |).

Comment: All those nested calls are not only expensive, but a maintenance nightmare.  I highly suggest you simplify that lest your name be cursed by future maintainers of that code. Simplify and be praised by future generations instead! That would not pass a good code review in its current state. I don't mean to be harsh, just trying to break a bad habit before it starts my friend.  :-)